# WiFi connection spotty for certain (public) networks

Tags: networking, drivers

My Wifi connection is spotty for **only certain WiFi networks**. It would work fine but every few minutes would disconnect, sometimes returning and sometimes not depending on the network. Often I can reconnect by restarting the driver using rmmod and modprobe. But the problem returns. Other devices (Windows, iOS, Android, etc.) can connect to the network without a problem.

The bad networks seem to be the ones in public areas. For example, right now I cannot connect to this network:

`>> iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"************"

          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: 94:F6:65:34:D3:78

          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm

          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-28 dBm

          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:210   Missed beacon:0`

I keep ignoring to fix this problem because usually the WiFi network I'm using works perfectly. However, at times I'm stuck with only one option for the WiFi network which has this problem.

This is my driver info returned by `lspci -vvnn`:

`03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8195]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at f1c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
    Kernel modules: rtl8192ce`

Also, if this is useful, I ran `lsmod | grep rtl` and got:

`rtl8192ce              61440  0
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8192ce
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_pci,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192ce
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192ce
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             520192  39 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel`

I have a Lenovo X230 with Ubuntu 16.04 (although previous Ubuntu versions had often the same problem.) I've followed many suggestions to fix this issue but I think none solved it, including changing driver parameters (turning off the 'N' and ignoring IPV6.) I hope I can fix this because it is very frustrating. Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: There's no fix unless you can access the router/AP and you can't. This is likely a problem with WiFi encryption settings - using TKIP instead of the recommended AES - and/or old routers without WPA2 support. And before you ask this happens with certain WiFi devices in Linux only.

Comment: This happens on open WiFi network, which require you to sign in through a webpage. I think those are probably not encrypted. Correct? I ran `iwlist wlan0 scan` and didn't see any encryption on one such network.

Comment: Correct, those are not encrypted. The problem is different and I have no solution for that. I had the same problem in a few coffee shops and the login page doesn't show up.

Comment: On this other network where I have problems, I'm seeing
`                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK`
Is it a driver problem, where drivers can't handle these different encryption types?